# How to properly run a extension test using JUnit's Test Engine?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have written a JUnit Extension which generates some reports after a test is executed.

I wanted to make a test case that ensures the extension works as expected and found this SO:

[How to test JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5) Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177422/how-to-test-junit-jupiter-junit-5-extensions)

Following the guides I managed to get to a point where my test is working, but is "flaky", because `ExampleExtensionTest` is executed twice - once as part of the main `junit` execution (`gradle test`) and once as part of the `extensionShouldGenerateReport()` test case.

As per JUnit's docs I could just change `static class ExampleExtensionTest` into `class ExampleExtensionTest` and JUnit won't pick it up. The problem then is that it's not picked up inside `extensionShouldGenerateReport()` as well!

It looks like I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my test case:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor;
import org.junit.platform.testkit.engine.EngineExecutionResults;
import org.junit.platform.testkit.engine.EngineTestKit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectClass;

public class ExtensionTest
{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtensionTest.class);

    @Test
    public void extensionShouldGenerateReport() throws IOException
    {

        Path reportPath = Path.of("build/tmp/example-recorded-test");
        logger.info("Configured report path: {}", reportPath);

        EngineTestKit.engine(JupiterEngineDescriptor.ENGINE_ID)
                     .selectors(selectClass(ExtensionTest.ExampleExtensionTest.class))
                     .execute()
                     .containerEvents()
                     .assertStatistics(stats -> stats.started(1).succeeded(1));

        // Assert all files were generated.
        assertThat(reportPath.toFile().exists()).isTrue();
        assertThat(reportPath.resolve("index.html").toFile().exists()).isTrue();
        assertThat(reportPath.resolve("metadata.json").toFile().exists()).isTrue();

    }

    @ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
    static class ExampleExtensionTest
    {
        @MyAnnotation(reportPath = "build/tmp/example-recorded-test")
        public void test()
        {
            return; // noop.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that "flanky" is the word you were looking for

Comment: Yeah, typo... fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours wasted on this problem, I found a way to fix this issue.

The easiest and most non-intrusive way is to use the `@EnabledIfSystemProperty(name = "some-property")` annotation over the `ExampleExtensionTest`.

Here's the code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor;
import org.junit.platform.testkit.engine.EngineExecutionResults;
import org.junit.platform.testkit.engine.EngineTestKit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import static org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectClass;

public class ExtensionTest
{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtensionTest.class);

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll()
    {
        System.setProperty("my-property", "true");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll()
    {
        System.clearProperty("my-property");
    }

    @Test
    public void extensionShouldGenerateReport() throws IOException
    {

        Path reportPath = Path.of("build/tmp/example-recorded-test");
        logger.info("Configured report path: {}", reportPath);

        EngineTestKit.engine(JupiterEngineDescriptor.ENGINE_ID)
                     .selectors(selectClass(ExtensionTest.ExampleExtensionTest.class))
                     .execute()
                     .containerEvents()
                     .assertStatistics(stats -> stats.started(1).succeeded(1));

        // Assert all files were generated.
        assertThat(reportPath.toFile().exists()).isTrue();
        assertThat(reportPath.resolve("index.html").toFile().exists()).isTrue();
        assertThat(reportPath.resolve("metadata.json").toFile().exists()).isTrue();

    }

    @ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
    @EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "my-property", matches = "true")
    static class ExampleExtensionTest
    {
        @MyAnnotation(reportPath = "build/tmp/example-recorded-test")
        public void test()
        {
            return; // noop.
        }
    }

}
```

This will cause the test to be excluded from the global run, but still work when it's programatically called via the `EngineTestKit`.

Comment: when asserting that files exist, one should always keep in mind that they may have been left over from a previous run, even if the current one failed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. This particular test case is not my best work - I would normally have some random string generated, but in this case it's not really possible. I agree with you, although in this particular case the test is always executed in a disposable docker container in k8s and the build command is always `gradle clean build`, so the resources will always be disposed after the CI has collected all the artifacts. :)